# JPA CriteriaBuilder equal blocking

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, criteria

I've experienced some strange problems with the criteria builder when I was using CriteriaBuilder.equal() to create predicate and pass it to CriteriaQuery.where() so I can filter a select by where clause. Everything runs fine but when it comes to the part with Criteria.equal It terminates everything after it. I have no idea how this is even happening.

```
    CriteriaBuilder builder = getCurrentSession().getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<User> criteria = builder.createQuery(User.class);
    Root<User> UserRoot = criteria.from(User.class);
    Predicate predicate = builder.equal(UserRoot.get("google_id"), googleId);
    criteria.select(UserRoot).where(predicate);
    return getCurrentSession().createQuery(criteria).getSingleResult();
```

After i put prints after each line they print until 4th line after that everything just disappears it gives no return. Every other operation excluding criterias are working fine.

Comment: `Terminates` as in throws an `Exception`?

Comment: just to mention it, UserRoot should be userRoot since it's a variable.

Comment: Found the problem... userRoot.get gets the variable name in the User entity, not the mapped with @Column(name="value") name. So it turns out that I have to put googleId there not google_id. Thanks for taking the time to answer. Silly mistakes